# New Asset images suddenly not showing

Tags: nuxt.js

Hello I am using NuxtJS v2.11.0..

At first everytime I add an image I can easily access it in my local URL like http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/img/img5.png... But after I have 18 images.. I can not access the next ones anymore like http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/img/dayan.jpg.. It will just show a blank page which is a sign of 404 on NuxtJS' end. This is my 3rd application using NuxtS and this has never happened to me before

My environment is in a MACbook running a linux container with an image of node:10.16.0... It is run by `npm run dev`

Comment: can you add code how you are using images is it with image tag or background image

Comment: I already solved it and I already updated my question

Comment: Answers do not belong in the question. Place it as an answer.

Comment: @Rob, updated my question and posted a new answer

Answer (score -1):

**This is already solved.**

Let me explain first the sequence that led me to this state. I upgraded my ELementUI to 2.13.0 to use `<el-image>`. I forced my NuxtJS to use `<el-image>` even though the assets is not yet compatible where I did something like `<el-image src="/_nuxt/assets/img/dayan.jpg"></el-image>`. I then tried to even visit the URL in the browser but it did not show. But when I tried `<img src="~assets/img/dayan.jpg">`it then became available in the browser then when I tried `<el-image src="/_nuxt/assets/img/dayan.jpg"></el-image>`. What I did not know is you really need to try to `src` the asset first before they become available. A weird behaviour if you ask me